# How can I return a real JavaScript array from a Java method with Nashorn?

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, nashorn

I'm writing an API to be used by some JavaScript code.  Some of the methods in this API should return a real JavaScript array.  Unfortunately, this doesn't work:

```
// MyApi.java
public class MyApi {
    String[] returnsJavaArray();

    List<String> returnsJavaList();
}

// MyScript.js
var api = getMyApi();
var strings = api.returnsJavaArray(); // Returns some kind of proxy
strings = api.returnsJavaList(); // Also a proxy
```

While the proxies support basic things like `strings[i]`, I need them to be actual arrays in order to use some Array polyfills.  What's the best way to do this in Nashorn?

My only idea so far is to write a JavaScript wrapper of the whole `MyApi` and wrap the results with `Java.from(api.returnsJavaArray())` but that's pretty tedious.

Answer (score -1):

You should make you API return a string of js.
Then, in your js file, you can call

```
eval(stringOfJsReturnFromServer);
```

To make your script run

Comment: From server?  There's no server/client relationship, this is Nashorn running the JS code directly in the JVM.